# regular expression to allow only integer and decimal no precision required

Tags: javascript, regex, jsp

This is a duplicate post, The requirement is little different though, I want to know a regular expression that would allow only decimal numbers. Found a similar solution here.

[regular expression to allow only integer and decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12475704/5086633)
  but the solution has a comma in it.

I dont need the comman at all in the Regex exp.

```
/^[0-9]+([\,\.][0-9]+)?$/g; answer found on the site
```

I applied my logic based on the explaination in the post.

```
/^[0-9]+([\.][0-9]+)?$/g; My modification
```

Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: are you runnig java or javascript?

Comment: It should do what you are after. A slightly cleaner way of writing the same expression would be to use this: `/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/g`. In regular expression syntax, the `\d` is the same as `[0-9]`.

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: In that case you need to replace `/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/g` with `/^\d*(\.\d+)?$/g`.

Comment: @marianoc84's answer technically took care of something mine did not. Besides, there is no major difference between our answers, so I do not think that anything useful will be added if I post another answer. What matters is that the question has been answered correctly :).

Comment: i like that stmt :) "what matters is that ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right way to call:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^[0-9]*([\.][0-9]+)?$/g);
console.log(regex.test('0.85'));  // true
console.log(regex.test('0,85'));  // false
console.log(regex.test('.35'));   // true  
console.log(regex.test(''));      // false   
console.log(regex.test('.'));     // false
console.log(regex.test('4'));     // true
```

I suggest a little modification on the regular expression, I've changed the multiplicity of the first block to `zero or more` so `.35` will be considered valid, as you ask in the comment above.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zwUi1OVtD97wwxFFm3sB?p=preview) is a plunker.

Comment: zero or more, I'm sorry

Comment: @npinti thanks for the response too... :) /^\d*(\.\d+)?$/g